# How to fetch the dynamic row in table body using jquery

Tags: c#, html, jquery, .net

In c# i'm creating dynamically a single row for testing like this

```
   dynamic tbl =   "<tr>";
    foreach(var tran in  Transactions)
    {
     this.tbl = this.tbl + "<td>"+tran["transaction_number"]+"</td>";
    }
    this.tbl = this.tbl + "</tr>";
   ViewData["tblValue"]  = this.tbl;
```

then in jQuery I'm appending the  values in table tbody like this

```
   var _myNames = '@ViewData["tblValue"]';       
            tableBody = $("table tbody");
            tableBody.append(_myNames);
```

and this is my html table example

```
<table id="tblTransactions" class="table-striped">
    <thead>
        <th scope="col">Transaction No</th>       
    </thead>
        <tbody id="tbody">
        </tbody>   
</table>
```

finally i'm getting output like a string value. It's not appending as htmll.
let me know the change i've to do .. thanks

[image]

Comment: `dynamic tbl =   "<tr>";` ew, why? It's clearly a string.

Comment: Have you tried `tableBody.html(_myNames);`

Comment: @ Carsten i've tried  tableBody.html(_myNames);  it also giving same output

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here other than dynamically create HTML. Take a look at Razor and if you really want to get into it Blazor. No need for Javascript at all, just plain C# in the browser.

Comment: @Paul I'm trying something like this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-dynamically-add-remove-table-rows-using-jquery/  at some point we needed this dynamic html rows

Comment: You can do `Html.Raw(myHtmlString)` directly in the page, no js required.  If you really want to do it the way you have, you can do `var _myNames = $('@ViewData["tblValue"]');` to make the string an actual html object that can be appended.